# Websocket - Disconnection of the user Android/iOS during the app in background and during the eve

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, nginx, proxy

I have a Node.JS application that is a generalist chat, the application uses the websocket and I noticed that from time to time there are users who automatically disconnect from the websocket when the application is in the background , while they are on another application and it is the same thing when the Smartphone is in standby.

it apparently affects everyone who has Android and iOS.

Do you have an idea to solve the problems?

Answer (score 0):

On Android you'll need to have a background service that keeps the websocket alive. When onPause is inoked it'll need to submit the service with the non-obviously named startForegroundService command, this tells Android not to kill it.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)

On iOS I'm not so sure, but my guess is that it'll be less straigttforward.

Comment: Ok thank, I had already heard about this ForegroundServices. Do you know if it is possible to use another system like a Web Workers? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Hi, there is a tutorial or a demo that explains how to put startForegroundService?